# How to check python-logging logs in a Docker container micro-service

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, python-logging

I've just started to use Docker.

I'm working on a project coded by another developer. In the project Docker container, I have three micro-services (aggregatore, classificatore, testmicro), each using python module `logging` for debugging purposes.

My issue is that I can't figure out where I can view the `logging` output.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  files:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
     [..]

  grafana:
     [..]

  prometheus:
     [..]

  aggregatore:
   [..] 

  classificatore:
    build: classificatore/.
    volumes:    
      - [..]
    volumes_from: 
      - files
    ports: 
      - [..]
    command: ["python", "/src/main.py"]
    depends_on: 
      rabbit:
        condition: service_healthy

  testmicro:
    [..]    
  rabbit:
    [..]
```

I the terminal, I run

```
$docker-compose up -d
```

this launches all the microservices.

Let's focus on classificatore service.

**classificatore/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3
RUN mkdir /src
ADD requirements.txt /src/.
WORKDIR /src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /src/.
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/reqdoc
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

**classificatore/main.py**

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('pika').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
log = logging.getLogger()
[..]
app = Flask( __name__ , template_folder='./web')

@app.route("/")
def index(message=None):
    log.info("classificatore index!! ")
    [..]
    return render_template('index.html', files1=files1, files2=files2, message=message)
```

In the code above, where does the output text "`classificatore index`" go?

Thank you for any support you can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`docker logs classificatore`

Another way would be `docker exec -it classificatore bash` and then fool around in your container

Comment: Thank you @LeCoon. I get $ docker logs classificatore
Error: No such container: classificatore/

Comment: use `docker container ps ` and check your desired container id or container name and pass it to `docker logs` command. If you want to check your logs "live" check my answer.

Comment: Exactly, are you sure that you `docker-compose up -d` worked ? As @michalk said, `docker ps` will help you out finding your container.

Comment: Thank you @LeCoonzarakailloux, now I can see the stdout! The problem now is that Docker is not compiling my classificatore/main.py, actually I think Docker is using source files located elsewhere. I know is off-topic, I'll ask it in a new question.

Comment: Please send me the link, I think I have an idea about it

Comment: @LeCoonzarakailloux here we are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955422/why-docker-is-not-compiling-my-micro-service-source-files

Answer (score 3):

You should modify your Dockerfile to run python script with unbuffered option.

> -u : unbuffered binary stdout and stderr; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x see man page for details on internal buffering relating to '-u'

```
CMD ["python", "-u", "main.py"]
```

Answer (score 2):

As posted in other answers you can use [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) command. Or if you want to attach your current terminal’s standard input, output, and error (or any combination of the three) to a running container, look at [docker attach](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/) command. This will let you to inspect your logs "live".