# Why Docker is not compiling my micro-service source files?

Tags: docker

I've just started to use Docker.

I'm working on a project coded by another developer. In the project Docker container, I have three micro-services (aggregatore, classificatore, testmicro).

In `classificatore/`, I have:

**classificatore/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3
RUN mkdir /src
ADD requirements.txt /src/.
WORKDIR /src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /src/.
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/reqdoc
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

I build-up the app by running:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I've realised that Docker is not compiling the source files in the project folder but it is using the ones in the dir `/src` created by classificatore/Dockerfile. I can't find this dir.

How can I tell docker to use the files in my project location?

I'm using PyCharm, don't know if it is an useful info :-)

**EDIT 1**:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  files:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
     [..]

  grafana:
     [..]

  prometheus:
     [..]

  aggregatore:
   [..] 

  classificatore:
    build: classificatore/.
    volumes:    
      - [..]
    volumes_from: 
      - files
    ports: 
      - [..]
    command: ["python", "/src/main.py"]
    depends_on: 
      rabbit:
        condition: service_healthy

  testmicro:
    [..]    
  rabbit:
    [..]
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Your `docker-compose.yml` file is probably relevant too: there’s a very common pattern that hides everything the `Dockerfile` does.

Comment: no error messages. If for ex. I edit main.py by changing a logging message, I can't see the changes. I guess because the Docker compiler is not compiling the files I expect.

Comment: @DavidMaze I added the docker compose file. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-compose up -d` will build an image for services that declare a build if and only if no image exists already in your local docker registry. If you `docker-compose down` and start over, the next call will simply start containers with the already existing image.

To update an existing image and run a new container out of it, you have to specifically ask for a build.

```sh
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

An other options is to use the `--build` option.

```sh
docker-compose up -d --build
```

You might find other useful scenarios by inspecting the help:

```sh
docker-compose --help
docker-compose build --help
docker-compose up --help
```